# figure out how many times a word comes up

Tags: php, string, search

`dogdogdogdogsdogdogdogs`

how would I count how many times "dog" and "dogs" appeared without regex?

Comment: do you care about boundaries? eg "This is a thesis", so for the word "is", the result you want is 3 right ?

Comment: Looking at his string, he doesn't. But good point @ghostdog, I expanded my answer taking into consideration what you say.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [**substr_count()**](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

> **substr_count()** returns the number of times the needle  substring occurs in the haystack  string. Please note that needle  is case sensitive.

**However**, you say you want to count the occurrences of `dog` **and** `dogs`. If you check for `dogs` first and then for `dog`, you will get skewed results (because `dogs` gets counted twice).

If your example is literally `dog` and `dogs`, you need to subtract the count for `dogs` from that for `dog` to get the proper count.

If you are working on a programmatic approach with varying words, you will need to check beforehand whether any of the words are a part of another word.

Cheers to SilentGhost for the simpler approach.

Comment: can't you just subtract the count of the long word from the count of the short word? why all these complications?

Comment: @SilentGhost: It can become harder to understand if we're dealing with several overlapping strings.

Comment: @Alix: hm, are we? how will this whole thing work in this case?

Comment: @SilentGhost: I don't know, the example provided doesn't seem to be a real world application. I had the exact same though you did, just making a point - chill out.

Comment: @Alix the point is good. It gets *real* tough with overlapping strings.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`substr_count()`](http://php.net/substr_count).

```
substr_count('dogdogdogdog', 'dog');
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`substr_count`](http://php.net/substr_count) function should do just what you're asking :

```
$str = 'dogdogdogdogsdogdogdogs';
$a = substr_count($str, 'dog');
var_dump($a);
```

Will get you :

```
int 7
```

Quoting its documentation page :

```
int substr_count  ( string $haystack  , string $needle  
    [, int $offset = 0  [, int $length  ]] )
```

> `substr_count()` returns the number of
>   times the needle  substring occurs in
>   the haystack  string. Please note that
>   needle  is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

[substr_count](http://php.net/substr-count)

```
substr_count('dogdogdogdogsdogdogdogs', 'dog');
// returns 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, besides `substr_count()` you can also use the good old [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$string = 'dogdogdogdogsdogdogdogs';

$str = str_replace('dogs', '', $string, $count);
echo 'Found ' . $count . ' time(s) "dogs" in ' . $string;

$str = str_replace('dog', '', $str, $count);
echo 'Found ' . $count . ' time(s) "dog" in ' . $string;
```

This approach solves [the problem Pekka mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236422/figure-out-how-many-times-a-word-comes-up/2236438#2236438). As an added benefit you can also **use [`str_ireplace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) for case insensitive search**, something that `substr_count()` isn't capable of.

From the PHP Manual:

> `substr_count()` returns the number of
>   times the *needle* substring occurs in
>   the *haystack* string. **Please note
>   that *needle* is case sensitive.**